# Simple way of parsing in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regex. I would like to parse the following data. I have come up with some regular expressions that seem to work on sublime but when  i test it in visual studio it won't work. i was wondering if someone can provide a simple example or guidance on how to parse this using regex. It must be very simple and must be my mistake i understand so apologize in advance.

Here is the data i am dealing with.

```
Fri 11:00 - 12:00
                            Max Agents: 1
                            Min Agents: 2
                            Total Calls: 3
                            Answered Calls: 4
                            Abandoned Calls: 5
                            Average Time to Answer (secs): 6
                            Longest Time to Answer (secs): 7
                            Average Time in Call (secs): 8
                            Longest Time in Call (secs): 9
                            Average Time before Abandon (secs): 10
                            Per agent statistics:
                              Agent: 1001
                                From Direct Call:
                                  Total Calls Answered : 11
                                  Average Time in Call (secs) : 12
                                  Longest Time in Call (secs) : 13
                                From Queue:
                                  Total Calls Answered : 2
                                  Average Time in Call (secs) : 14
                                  Longest Time in Call (secs) : 15
                              Agent: 1002
                                From Direct Call:
                                  Total Calls Answered : 1
                                  Average Time in Call (secs) : 16
                                  Longest Time in Call (secs) : 17
                                From Queue:
                                  Total Calls Answered : 2
                                  Average Time in Call (secs) : 18
                                  Longest Time in Call (secs) : 19
                            Queue related statistics:
                              Total calls presented to the queue: 20
                              Calls answered by agents: 21
                              Number of calls in the queue: 22
                              Average time to answer (secs): 23
                              Longest time to answer (secs): 24
                              Number of abandoned calls: 25
                              Average time before abandon (secs): 26
                              Calls forwarded to voice mail: 27
                              Calls answered by voice mail: 28
                              Number of error calls: 29
```

This is the one and its only getting the Agent:1004 part.

```
Agent:.(?<agentNum>\d+)\n?((?:[a-z\s]+from.*\n)+\s(?:[a-z\s]+call.*\n)+)?((?:[a-z\s]+from.*\n)+[\n\s]+(?:[a-z\s]+call.*\n)+)?
```

I am trying to extract data of the different attributes such as
Total calls answered
Average Time in call

etc . I basically want to extract data for those kind of fields and store in a table.

Comment: Perhaps you can post the regex you're trying to use and how you're attempting to use it in C# in Visual Studio?

Comment: The regex used in the search/replace functions in visual studio is not the same as what C# uses. Try testing here instead: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: Why would you do that with regexs?

Comment: You should update your question to include the desired output as well as the Regex strings as Chris suggested.

Comment: Why not just use a simple parser generator like ANTLR or gppg/gplex?

Comment: I just posted the regex sorry for not posting before.

Comment: How would ANTLR work? It is also to be noted i am working with framework 3.5

Comment: I would recommend parsing this with conventional string methods. `foreach (line in someLines){ if line.startswith("Agent: ") { etc... `

Comment: You wanna parse this whole shebang with one regex? It's a recursive data structure with variable number of elements. ANTLR or build some simple state machine to track your state and parse it line-by-line.

Comment: Like Jeremy, I'd be interested in which part of the data you're trying to extract.

Comment: I am basically trying to parse the different parts such as Total  calls answered, average time in calls etc.

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? Is this just a txt file, a xml file, something else? Also are those spaces fixed with, are they tabs, how are the indents defined?

Comment: @MikePrecup: Visual Studio finally added support for .NET regexes (in the 2012 version, think).  But I suspect the OP is using the regexes his C# code, which he happens to be editing with VS; we see that a lot.

Comment: @AlanMoore Oh, interesting, thanks for the information. My dev work all happens in 2008 and 2010, so I hadn't found that. That was a much needed change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the text is well formed and always prints out in the same order I would not use regex at all, I would go line by line and parse the text out with functions.

```
class CallCenterActivity
{
    public CallCenterActivity(string callActivity)
    {
        AgentStistics = new List<AgentStatistic>();

        using(var reader = new StringReader(callActivity))
        {
             ActivityDate = ParseActivityDate(reader.ReadLine());
             MaxAgents = ExtractInt(reader);
             MinAgents = ExtractInt(reader);
             //(Snip)
             AvarageTimeBeforeAbandon = ExtractInt(reader);

             if(reader.ReadLine().Trim().Equals("Per agent statistics:") == false)
                 throw new InvalidDataException("We where not on the line we expected to be for \"Per Agent statistics:\"");

             string currentLine;
             //This loops till we break out of the agent section
             while((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()).Trim().Equals("Queue related statistics:") == false)
             {
                  var agent = new AgentStatistic();
                  agent.AgentId = ExtractInt(reader);
                  agent.DirectCallsAnswered = ExtractInt(reader);
                  //(snip)
                  agent.QueueLongestTimeInCall = ExtractInt(reader);

                  AgentStistics.Add(agent);
             }

             TotalCallsPresentedToQueue = ExtractInt(reader);
             //(Snip)
             CallsAnsweredByVoiceMail = ExtractInt(reader);
        }

    }

    //These parser methods are small and kept static so you could easily write unit tests against each parser.
    private static DateTime ParseActivityDate(string activityDateLine)
    {
        throw new NotImplmentedException("Here you would turn your \"Fri 11:00 - 12:00\" in to a DateTime");
    }

    //ParseInt and ExtractInt are separated to ease Unit Testing.
    private static int ParseInt(string line)
    {
        var split = line.Split(':')
        return Int32.Parse(split[1]);
    }

    private static int ExtractInt(StringReader reader)
    {
        return ParseInt(reader.ReadLine());
    }

    public DateTime ActivityDate {get;set;}
    public int MaxAgents {get;set;}
    public int MinAgents {get;set;}
    public int TotalCalls {get;set;}
    public int AnsweredCalls {get;set;}
    public int AbandonedCalls {get;set;}
    public int AvarageTimeToAnswer {get;set;}
    public int LongestTimeToAnswer {get;set;}
    public int AvarageTimeBeforeAbandon {get;set;}
    public List<AgentStatistic> AgentStistics {get; private set;}
    public int TotalCallsPresentedToQueue {get;set;}
    public int CallsAnsweredByAgents {get;set;}
    public int NumberOfCallsInTheQueue {get;set;}
    public int AvarageTimeToAnswerQueue {get;set;}
    public int LongestTimeToAnswerQueue {get;set;}
    public int NumberOfAbandondCalls {get;set;}
    public int AvarageTimeBeforeAbandon {get;set;}
    public int CallsForwaredToVoiceMail {get;set;}
    public int CallsAnsweredByVoiceMail {get;set;}
}

class AgentStatistic
{
    public int AgentId {get;set;}
    public int DirectCallsAnswered {get;set;}
    public int DirectCallsAverageTimeInCall {get;set;}
    public int DirectCallsLongestTimeInCall {get;set;}
    public int QueueAnswered {get;set;}
    public int QueueAverageTimeInCall {get;set;}
    public int QueueLongestTimeInCall {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: return Int.Parse(split[1]);

I get an error on this line . 
The name "Int" does no exist in the current context.

Comment: That was a typo, that should either be `int` or `Int32`, depending on your coding preference.

Comment: Yea thanks, i did change it to int32 and it gives error.
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: I am not your personal debugger, put breakpoints in, look at the string that is being feed in, and see why it is not parsing. Off of the top of my head change it to `return Int32.Parse(split[1].Trim());` but without sitting down with you with the debugger I can't tell you more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but here is how you parse out parts of a string using Regex.

```
Regex ex = new Regex("[0-9]*"); //generic regular expression -- look for numbers
Match match = ex.Match(searchString, startAtIndex);
while(match.Success)
{
    string currentMatch = match.Value;

     //do something


    match = match.NextMatch()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `.` in your regex a lot, I'd advise you to avoid it. Rather, match a large group of characters you're not interested in by matching *[anything that's **not** what I **am** interested in]*. In this case you wanna have the digits, correct?

I would do this (`\D` with capital D means [anything that isn't a digit]):

```
Agent:\s+(?<AgentNum>\d+)(?:\D+)(?<DirectTotal>\d+)(?:\D+)(?<DirectAvg>\d+)(?:\D+)(?<DirectLongest>\d+)(?:\D+)(?<QueueTotal>\d+)(?:\D+)(?<QueueAvg>\d+)(?:\D+)(?<QueueLongest>\d+)
```

I'm assuming the data set is always formatted like your example with the line-order never changed and numbers not omitted (but rather set to 0).

I don't have C# or anything to test whether I used the `(?<NameSubgroup>matchPattern)` correct and I'm not familiar with the methods C# has to iterate through the matches and extract the named subgroups, but this should get you on the right path.

The `?:` inside `(?:\D+)` makes sure that the groups of non-digits don't get captured into subgroups in the languages I'm used too working with.